# what are the modules will be loaded by default with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently I am reading some official doc about Modules and Import systems about python.
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import

I notice that sys.modules which holds all the modules which have been loaded.

If I run a script like

```
import sys
print(sys.modules.keys())
```

I shall get the names for the modules which have been loaded by default except the sys module. (since I have import sys explicitly, but it may also be loaded by default because the import statement will first check whether the module to be imported has been loaded, if not then it will do the loading and initialization action).

I found that there is a set of modules called builtin modules,  but I checked it with sys.builtin_module_names and found there are only part of them are loaded by default. And I also noticed that there are also some modules loaded by default come from the Python Standard Module/Library https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#standard-modules  https://docs.python.org/3/library/. (Maybe the Python Standard should also contains all the builtin_modules)

So I want to know what is the format for these modules which will been loaded by default.  Is there any official explanation about it?

Comment: This is an implementation detail, there is no guarantee or explicit set of modules that will be loaded at interpreter startup

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the documentation for "standard modules" that you linked to:

> Python comes with a library of standard modules, described in a
> separate document, the Python Library Reference (“Library Reference”
> hereafter). Some modules are built into the interpreter; these provide
> access to operations that are not part of the core of the language but
> are nevertheless built in, either for efficiency or to provide access
> to operating system primitives such as system calls.

Comment: No, this doesn't address the question. This is simply discussion the *standard library*, but that doesn't mean these modules will be loaded when the interpreter starts by default.